# I removed /snap, what to do?

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation

I'm a linux newbie. I wanted to delete a program and accidentally typed `sudo rm -r /snap`. Now I can't start some programs.

For instance when I type `opera` in my terminal to open opera it says

```
Command 'opera' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo snap install opera
```

But when I type in `sudo snap install opera` it says

```
snap "opera" is already installed, see 'snap help refresh'
```

And if I try `rm opera` it says

```
rm: cannot remove 'opera': No such file or directory
```

What sould I do?

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get --reinstall install snapd` to get back **snap**.

Comment: I wouldn't let snap near my PC - so that would be one solution. You are now  locked into the Ubuntu ecosystem.